# Remove view from dynamically added Button

Tags: android, sorting, view

I have programs that will fetch and show some data from database, and

I want to create a sort function that will sort data based on Posting Date, Priority, and Alphabet.
(I'm using spinner for this, so user will choose from the spinner).

When user change their sorting preference, My program will delete all the fetched data and refetch new Data from database.

I have successfully fetch and show data from database, and I have successfully sort the data as well, but when I want to show the latest sorted data, there is some problem with the view.

My problem is all the data are not completely removed, I want to remove the dynamically added button not all the view..

I've tried using layout.removeView(button), but it just remove the last created button, not all the button

Here is my code :

```
public class ViewTaskToDoList extends Activity {
    userSessionManager session;
    String Username, taskId, groupId, sortBy;
    Database myDb;
    LinearLayout layout;
    Spinner spinner;
    Button newBtDate, newBtPriority, newBtAlphabet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_task_todolist);
    sessionAndDeclaration();
    dbConstructor();
}

private void dbConstructor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sortBy = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sortBy, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
            String[] getOption = getResources().getStringArray(
                    R.array.SortBy);
            String getSelected = getOption[index];
            myDb.open();
            int totalRow = myDb.countHowManyTaskToDoList(groupId, taskId);
            myDb.close();
            if (getSelected.equals("Posting Date")) {

                myDb.open();

                String todolistIdByDate[] = myDb
                        .fetchTaskTodolistByPostingDate(groupId, taskId);
                String[] todolistTitleByDate = new String[todolistIdByDate.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < totalRow; i++) {
                    todolistTitleByDate[i] = myDb
                            .getTodolistTitle(todolistIdByDate[i]);
                    newBtDate = new Button(ViewTaskToDoList.this);
                    newBtDate.setText(todolistTitleByDate[i]);
                    layout.addView(newBtDate);
                }

                myDb.close();
            } else if (getSelected.equals("Priority")) {

                myDb.open();
                String todolistByPriority[] = myDb
                        .fetchTaskTodolistByPriority(groupId, taskId);
                String[] todolistTitleByPriority = new String[todolistByPriority.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < totalRow; i++) {
                    todolistTitleByPriority[i] = myDb
                            .getTodolistTitle(todolistByPriority[i]);
                    newBtPriority = new Button(ViewTaskToDoList.this);
                    newBtPriority.setText(todolistTitleByPriority[i]);
                    layout.addView(newBtPriority);
                }
                myDb.close();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sort based on Priority", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else if (getSelected.equals("A-Z")) {

                myDb.open();

                String todolistByAlphabet[] = myDb
                        .fetchTaskTodolistByAlphabet(groupId, taskId);
                String[] todolistTitleByAlphabet = new String[todolistByAlphabet.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < totalRow; i++) {
                    todolistTitleByAlphabet[i] = myDb
                            .getTodolistTitle(todolistByAlphabet[i]);
                    newBtAlphabet = new Button(ViewTaskToDoList.this);
                    newBtAlphabet.setText(todolistTitleByAlphabet[i]);
                    layout.addView(newBtAlphabet);
                }
                myDb.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sort based on A-Z", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}

private void sessionAndDeclaration() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    session = new userSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    // get name
    Username = user.get(userSessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);

    myDb = new Database(this);
    Intent getIntent = getIntent();
    groupId = getIntent.getStringExtra("passedGroupId");
    taskId = getIntent.getStringExtra("passedTaskId");
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutTasktodolist);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSortBy);
}

}
```

How can I fix this problem? Or if you have a better algorithm or code to fix my problem please let me know them,, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have reference of the last button(due to re assignment of your global button  variable in the loop where you created it) that's why you are able to remove only the last one.try to keep the reference of each dynamically created button then you will be able to remove it . you can try below code snippet.

```
 //declare globally
    ArrayList< Button> newBtDatelist=new ArrayList<Button>();
    //then  in your loop
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //here you create button locally 
            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText("button" + i);
            layout.addView(btn);
            newBtDatelist.add(btn);
        }
```

To remove the button dynamically you can do it like this.

```
private void remove() {
        for (int i = 0; i < newBtDatelist.size(); i++) {
             layout.removeView(newBtDatelist.get(i));
        }
        newBtDatelist.clear(); //to remove all the reference from the arraylist 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`for (int i = 0; i < totalRow; i++) {
                    todolistTitleByPriority[i] = myDb
                            .getTodolistTitle(todolistByPriority[i]);
                    newBtPriority = new Button(ViewTaskToDoList.this);
                     newBtPriority.setId(i)
                    newBtPriority.setText(todolistTitleByPriority[i]);
                    layout.addView(newBtPriority);
                }`

```
void delete(int id)
          {
Button btn=  (Button)layout.findviewbyid(id);
 btn.removeAllViews();
    }
```

*get button ID from parant layout and remove view by id dirrsctly   *

Comment: Could you please give me an example of yours?

Comment: It is within the if and else if code I provided above

Comment: check above code dear set button id first the delete it by ID